# How to export deform modifier animation into a game engine?

Tags: 3d, opengl-es, maya

Hi we animated a simple plane with deform modifier to give a folding cloth like effect. How do we export it from maya so that we are able to import into our game engine.

Can we export them as a single animated file with vertex info different for each frame ?

Answer (score 1):

You can export it in whatever way you want by writing your [own exporter plugin for Maya](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/apis-and-tools/how-to-write-a-simple-maya-model-exporter-r1906).

You could also try going via [FBX](http://usa.autodesk.com/fbx/) or another well supported format, and convert to your own format from that.

Answer (score 0):

You could export it as MDD, or another baked format.

Comment: MDD didn't have texture co-ordinates support ?